# Erro na conexão do banco de dados

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados

Estou fazendo um projeto e esta com um problema na parte do banco de dados. Criei um formulario para se cadastrar no site, mas quando coloca todos os dados para se cadastrar, essas informaçoes nao sao passadas pro banco de dados. Alguem sabe me dizer o que pode estar errado ?

formulario

```
            <div class="col-md-6 logo">
            Cadastre-se
            <form method="post" action="registra.php" id="cadastro">
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Digite seu nome completo" required="requiored">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="requiored">

                    <?php
                    if($erro_email){
                    echo '<font size="3px" color="#FF0000"> Esse email ja esta sendo usado em outra conta!</font>';
                }

                ?>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" name="senha" placeholder="Crie uma senha" required="requiored">
            </div>


            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default ">Cadastrar</button>
        </form>
        </div>
```

Conexao com o banco de dados

```
<?php

require_once('bancodedados.php');

 $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $senha = md5($_POST['senha']);

$objDB = new db();
$link = $objDB->conecta_mysql();

$email_existe = false;

$sql = "insert into usuarios(usuario, email, senha) values ('$usuario','$email','$senha')";

//verificar se o email ja existe
$sql = "select * from usuarios where email = '$email'";
if($resultado_id = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){

    $dados_usuario = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_id);

    if (isset($dados_usuario['email'])) {
        $email_existe = true;
    }  
} else {
    echo ' erro ao tentar localizar o email';
}

    if($email_existe){

        $retorno_get ='';

        $retorno_get.="erro_email=1&";

        header('Location:cadastreentrar.php?'.$retorno_get);
die();
    }

//executar querry
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    header('Location:home.php');
} else {
    echo 'Não foi possivel registrar o usuario';
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Você não está executando a query do insert, somente a do select. Vamos ao teste de mesa:

```
$sql = "insert into usuarios(usuario, email, senha) values ('$usuario','$email','$senha')";
//Criou a string do insert, chamada sql, e atribui o insert

$sql = "select * from usuarios where email = '$email'";
//Atribuiu o select para o sql (que continha o insert)

if($resultado_id = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
//Executou o comando do sql (select)
```

Percebeu o que você fez? Você criou o comando para inserir os valores no banco de dados, mas não o executou, você sobrepôs outra string sobre ele.

Para consertar, faça dessa maneira:

```
$sql = "select * from usuarios where email = '$email'";

if($resultado_id = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){ //Executa o select

    $sql2 = "insert into usuarios(usuario, email, senha) values ('$usuario','$email','$senha')";

    mysqli_query($link, $sql2); //Executa o insert
}
```

Dica: Seu código está muito complexo para executar coisas tão simples, tente melhora-lo e otimiza-lo.

Comment: Indicaria, também, já ir estudando PDO. Esses funções logo logo serão depreciadas também.